# D8: Cannot redirect user at onKernelRequest event

Tags: 8, redirection

I want to redirect the user at "onKernelRequest" event and I have this method:

```
  public function onKernelRequest($event) {
    // Restricts access to nodes (views/edit).
    if (!empty($event->getRequest()->attributes->get('node'))) {
      $nid = $event->getRequest()->attributes->get('node')->get('nid')->getValue()['0']['value'];
      if (!$this->accessCheckService->canUserAccessByNodeId($nid)) {
        $response = new RedirectResponse('/access-restricted-by-taxonomy-term');
        $response->send();
        return;
      }
    }
```

The response is being sent, but the user is not redirected to the given address (access-restricted-by-taxonomy-term). It seems that RedirectResponse takes no action at onKernelRequest event. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of sending the response yourself you can try to use the method `setResponse()` of `$event`:

```
$event->setResponse($response);
```